# query returns null or an error

Tags: php, mysql

I am probably having a syntax error in my MySQL query so it returns no result. Working with SimplaCMS so errors are turned off because the CMS conflicting with local server. So what am I missing? as always here is the code:

```
  $product=$variant['name'];
$this->db->query("SELECT id  FROM s_products WHERE name='$product' LIMIT 1");
```

What can cause this?

Comment: try executing the query directly in your phpmyadmin to check if there is some data.... and its good if you concatenate $product instead of typing it directly

Comment: Try printing the db error info just after the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimplaCMS manages their own database `$db` with a custom class. This custom class includes a method called [`->placehold`](http://simpladesign.ru/kolichestvo-prosmotrov-tovarov-dlya-simpla/).

An example of this in action would be:

```
$placeholder = $this->db->placehold("SELECT id FROM s_products WHERE name=? LIMIT 1", $product);
$this->db->query($placeholder);
//$this->db->results(); //results are now in this variable
```

Comment: More reference from SimplaCMS [here](https://github.com/pikusov/Simpla/blob/master/api/Comments.php).

Comment: `->db->query('SELECT id FROM s_products WHERE name=? LIMIT 1', $product)` should work too I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like

```
$this->db->query("SELECT id FROM `s_products` WHERE name='".$product."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the value of `$product` and the other String values like:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT id  FROM s_products WHERE name='".$product."' LIMIT 1");
```

See also the [reference documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to enclose the name in quotes like this

```
"SELECT id  FROM s_products WHERE name = '".$product".' LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

debug the sql , then  executing the query directly in mysql